# How to dynamically choose the files from SharePoint in Tableau Prep?

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, tableau-prep

I'd like to choose files based on its name and last modified date from the SharePoint/Onedrive folder and connect it to Tableau Prep.

The file that's chosen would vary each day based on the Last Modified Date and the Prep flow is scheduled to run for each day.

Basically, I'm looking for the WildCard Union option for the SharePoint connected files.